# Gatsby, problem with using SCSS Modules, css works normally but SCSS don't

Tags: javascript, css, web, sass, gatsby

I have a problem with CSS modules in Gatsby. Everything was working just fine until I had changed the file format of modules from CSS to scss. Of course, I have a sass plugin installed. The weirdest part is that the global style file works normally as scss without any problems. After changing the file format of modules from CSS to scss I'm getting this error in the terminal:

```
ERROR #98123 WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Mini CSS Extract Plugin Loader Invalid Options

options.modules should be object

File: src/components/modules/footer.module.scss

failed Re-building development bundle - 0.477s
```

Footer component code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import * as style from "../components/modules/footer.module.scss";

const Footer = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={props.color}>
        <p>Learn</p>
        <Link>HOW</Link>
       </div>
      <div className={props.color}>
         <ul>
          <li>Contact</li>
          <li>Privacy Policy</li>
          <li>Terms of use</li>
        </ul>
        <p className={style.feature}>follow us</p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img></img>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img></img>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img></img>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

    export default Footer;
```

Code from the module:

```
.feature {
  color: blue;
}
```

gatsby-config.js:

```
module.exports = {plugins: ["gatsby-plugin-react-helmet", `gatsby-plugin-sass`],};
```

Do you guys know what is the reason behind this error? I'm just guessing that it is something with project configuration, some problem with node, webpack, etc. but I've no idea what it is particularly. I've created a new project to test CSS modules and on the new project, it's working properly.

Comment: Just to check, Have you run `gatsby clean`?

Comment: Haven't done it. I've tried it now but after using Gatsby clean I'm still getting the same error. :(

Comment: I decided to create the project from scratch. I have no idea how to fix it. I think after I've installed plugin or something I had got message in terminal about possibility of use option "audit fix" or some like that. I think after I've used it everything crashed because even animations in gsap doesn't work properly now. So I think it will be faster to create new project. I also did a mistake with making separate folders for modules because they should be in the same folder with components. But even after changing that scss modules doesn't work but css are working fine. Strange. ;)